# How to modify inner HTML with jquery without div Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a process which automatically create html and js (rmarkdown).

I want to modify the inner html of my code, from 90 to 100.
I have jquery loaded so I can use it. My issue, here, is that the tag span that I want to modify don't have an id. How can I do this?

```
<div id="equities" class="section level3">
    <h3>Equities</h3>
    <div class="knitr-options" data-fig-width="576" data-fig-height="460">

    </div>
    <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">90</span>
</div>
```

Comment: use class or data attr or class and data attr like `$('[data-icon=fa-pencil].value-output')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do that, for parent `#id`, `class` or `attribute`. The fastest way in this case is `.class` and the slowest is the parent `#id`.

You can choose what you think is better for your case:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.value-output').text('100');
   $('[data-icon="fa-pencil"]').text('100');
   $('#equities span').text('100');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="equities" class="section level3">
    <h3>Equities</h3>
    <div class="knitr-options" data-fig-width="576" data-fig-height="460">

    </div>
    <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">90</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('[data-icon=fa-pencil].value-output').text('91')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="equities" class="section level3">
  <h3>Equities</h3>
  <div class="knitr-options" data-fig-width="576" data-fig-height="460">

  </div>
  <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">90</span>
</div>
```

1. Use class like `$('.value-output')`
2. Use  data attr like `$('[data-icon=fa-pencil]')`
3. Use class and data attr like `$('[data-icon=fa-pencil].value-output')`

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```js
$('[data-icon=fa-pencil]').text('Change Text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="equities" class="section level3">
    <h3>Equities</h3>
    <div class="knitr-options" data-fig-width="576" data-fig-height="460">

    </div>
    <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">90</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses querySelector logic when selecting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

This could also be achieved with jQuerys `find` method: https://api.jquery.com/find/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (confirm("switch it")) {
    jQuery("#equities .value-output").text(100);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="equities" class="section level3">
  <h3>Equities</h3>
  <div class="knitr-options" data-fig-width="576" data-fig-height="460">

  </div>
  <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">90</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.value-output').html('100');
});
```

This way the JQuery code actually runs.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says that you've multiple span for `90 to 100`, you can use `each()` to iterate through the elements and change their `text()` as per your need.

```
$('div#equities span.value-output').each(function(){
  $(this).text("New Added Text "+$(this).text());
});
```

```js
$('div#equities span.value-output').each(function(){
  $(this).text("New Added Text "+$(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="equities" class="section level3">
  <h3>Equities</h3>
  <div class="knitr-options" data-fig-width="576" data-fig-height="460">

  </div>
  <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">90</span>
  <br/>
  
  <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">91</span>
  <br/>
  
  <span class="value-output" data-icon="fa-pencil" data-color="#01bb69">92</span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function findFirstDescendant(parent, tagname)
{
   parent = document.getElementById(parent);
   var descendants = parent.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
   if ( descendants.length )
      return descendants[0];
   return null;
}

var header = findFirstDescendant("equities", "span");
```

check whether this suits for you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use JQuery find to achieve the functionality , 
can u try this

```
$( "#equities").find('span').text(100);
```